# How to get values from a dictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am new to *iOS*. I created a login page and everything works fine. I used *JSON* for checking username and password and got the response from server in a *dictionary* format. I want to extract the values from the *dictionary* and check them in my program.
The response which I get from the server is:

```
json: {
        error = 0;
        msg = "";
        value = {
                  user = false;
                };
      };
```

First I want to check if the value with the key *`error`* is *`0`* or *`1`*. Then I want to check the value with the key *`user`*. I don't know how I should code to check it. Can anyone help?

The code which I tried is below:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *respString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:loginJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    SBJsonParser *objSBJSONParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[objSBJsonParser objectWithString:respString]];

    NSLog(@"json: %@",json);

    NSString *error = [json objectForKey:@"error"];

    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

    if ([error isEqualToString:@"o"])
    {
        NSLog(@"login successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"login fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `NSDictionary`?

Comment: yes, i tried to do it using NSDictionary and how to programmatically get the value "false"

Comment: Post the code (by updating your question) you tried so people can help.

Comment: The code which i tried is:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368303/parsing-a-json-array-into-a-nsdictionary check it

Comment: Why are you comparing `error` with the string `@"o"`? That's a lowercase O, not a zero. And `error` will be a number, not a string.

Comment: You can try this code to get the user value

NSDictionary *dict = [json objectForKey:@"value"]; NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"user"]);

You can still optimize this code to make it in one line

Answer (score 18):

Using modern Objective-C, accessing things in arrays and dictionaries become easier.

You should use the following syntax:

`id<NSObject> value = dictionary[@"key"];`

Similarly,

`id<NSObject> value = array[1]; // 1 is the index`

Applying the above to the question:

`NSString *error = json[@"error"];`

`NSDictionary *value = json[@"value"];`

`BOOL user = [json[@"value"][@"user"] boolValue];`

As in the above line, nesting is allowed, but it is not a good practice.

Comment: i tried above code but its throwing exception. can u please tell how to code for user for getting the values "true" or "false".

Comment: so the first segment `json[@"value]` returns us the NSDictionaryObject containing the user attribute then accessing `json[@"value"][@"user"]` will return us the boolean as a NSNumber object (at least i think) then calling `BoolValue` on that will convert into a BOOL... I suspect that the exception is happening when we try to call `boolValue`, could you paste the exception?

Comment: [__NSDictionaryM boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756a050
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756a050'
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Try these in isolation to see if the individual calls work;
try `json[@"value"][@"user"]` and see what type the object is.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSNumber *error = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
if ([error intValue] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"login successful");

    NSDictionary *value = [json objectForKey:@"value"];
    NSNumber *user = [value objectForKey:@"user"];
    if ([user boolValue])
    {
        NSLog(@"user == true");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"user == false");
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"login failed");
}
```

Comment: The code for `user` is incorrect. `json` does not have a `user` key.

Comment: Move the code to get the user inside the "then" portion of the `if` statement and you have the right answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't have exact idea where he wants to write the code to check `user` value but inside `if` it's the most appropriate. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I made the suggestion because that is what I thought the OP stated but after reading again I see that it is unclear. But it makes sense to only check the user if there is no error.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionaries that normally returning from the server will be as a key value pair. if you are looking for accessing these values  that corresponds to a key, then these code may help you

```
NSString *varname = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionaryname objectForKey:@"key"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

For get **error** value from your `JSON` Dictionary.

```
NSString *error = [myJSONDicName objectForKey:@"error"];
```

For get **user** value from your `JSON` Dictionary.

```
NSString *error = [[myJSONDicName objectForKey:@"value"] objectForKey:@"user"];
```

**EDITED:**

You just need to change In your

```
if ([error isEqualToString:@"o"])
                            _^_
                             |
```

change `'o'` to `'0'`

Comment: Yes, the OP does. But the OP is incorrect. That's one of the reason the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @rmaddy - but in the case of OP.. he/she only need to check error is `0` or `1` then i think `isEqualToString` is work.

Comment: But the code will crash since `NSNumber` doesn't have an `isEqualToString:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy - `NSNumber`??? sorry but OP got it as NSString so not need to use  `NSNumber`..

Comment: As I said, the OP is wrong. Look at the JSON. The `0` is not in quotes, is not an `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {
          NSString *respstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:loginJsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSDictionary *dic = [responseString JSONValue];
         NSLog(@"%@",dic);
         NSNumber *error = [dic objectForKey:@"error"];
        if([error intValue] == 0)  {
           NSLog(@"login successful");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"login fail");
        }

        NSString *user = [value objectForKey:@"user"];
        BOOL userStatus = [user boolValue];
 }
```

Comment: The OP already has code for getting the dictionary from the JSON. That's not the question.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question. Keep going.