# how to parse json in iOS

Tags: ios, json, dictionary

this is the json string that i am receiving from the API:

```
"incentives_and_benefits" = "{\"food\":{\"0\":\"\"},\"commission\":{\"0\":\"\"},\"uniform\":{\"0\":\"\"},\"transport\":{\"0\":\"\"},\"extras\":{\"0\":\"\"}}";
```

and i assigned it to dictionary. Now I need to get the values inside the dictionary.
I tried using the solution given here: [How to get values from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970064/how-to-get-values-from-a-dictionary-in-ios)

Heres what I have so far:

```
    NSString *strIncentives = [[self.jobDetailDict objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"incentives_and_benefits"];
    NSData *jsonData = [strIncentives dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *e;
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&e];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", dict);

    NSString *food = [dict objectForKey:@"food"];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", food);
    NSString *commission = [dict objectForKey:@"commission"];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", commission);
    NSString *uniform = [dict objectForKey:@"uniform"];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", uniform);
    NSString *transport = [dict objectForKey:@"transport"];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", transport);
    NSString *extras = [dict objectForKey:@"extras"];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", extras);
```

Now I need to check whether food's value is 0 or 1..When Food's value is 1 then i need to get Hello string and display it. (this is just an example) **food: {"1":"Hello"}**

```
    if([food isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        //the string will be placed here
        NSLog(@"FOOD Available")
    }
```

when i reach the if statement i get an error:

```
[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

How will i be able to resolve this?
please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in iOS App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530173/how-to-parse-json-in-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([[dict objectForKey:@"food"]isEqualToString:@“”]){
    NSLog(@"FOOD Available")
 }
```